# How to use worker queues in SwiftNIO?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift-nio

I have a Swift NIO HTTP2 server which handles request within the context's event loop. But I want to process the request in another thread, GCD aync thread pool and get the result back and send it.

```
public func channelRead(context: ChannelHandlerContext, data: NIOAny) {
    context.eventLoop.execute {
       context.channel.getOption(HTTP2StreamChannelOptions.streamID).flatMap { streamID -> EventLoopFuture<Void> in 
            // ...
            var buffer = context.channel.allocator.buffer(capacity: respBody.count)
            buffer.writeString(respBody)        
            context.channel.write(self.wrapOutboundOut(HTTPServerResponsePart.body(.byteBuffer(buffer))), promise: nil)
            return context.channel.writeAndFlush(self.wrapOutboundOut(HTTPServerResponsePart.end(nil)))
        }.whenComplete { _ in
            context.close(promise: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

If I change it to use GCD global queue, how would I return the `EventLoopFuture<Void>` response?

```
context.eventLoop.execute {
    context.channel.getOption(HTTP2StreamChannelOptions.streamID).flatMap { streamID -> EventLoopFuture<Void> in
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            return self.send("hello world new ok", to: context.channel).whenComplete({ _ in
                _ = context.channel.writeAndFlush(self.wrapOutboundOut(HTTPServerResponsePart.end(nil)))
                context.close(promise: nil)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Is it okay to use GCD global queue in this way or how will I use worker threads?

---

The send string function calls the below function to write the body.

```
private func sendData(_ data: Data, to channel: Channel, context: StreamContext) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
    let headers = self.getHeaders(contentLength: data.count, context: context)
    _ = self.sendHeader(status: .ok, headers: headers, to: channel, context: context)
    var buffer = channel.allocator.buffer(capacity: data.count)
    buffer.writeBytes(data)
    let part = HTTPServerResponsePart.body(.byteBuffer(buffer))
    return channel.writeAndFlush(part)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rules in SwiftNIO are:

- operations on `Channel`s are thread-safe, so you can do them from any thread or queue
- operations on `ChannelHandlerContext` are *not* thread-safe and should only be done from within the `ChannelHandler`. All of the `ChannelHandler`'s events are called on the right `EventLoop`.

So your example is almost correct, just make sure to only use the `Channel` and never the `ChannelHandlerContext` from a `DispatchQueue` or any other thread (that isn't the channel's `EventLoop`).

```
let channel = context.channel // save on the EventLoop
channel.getOption(HTTP2StreamChannelOptions.streamID).flatMap { streamID -> EventLoopFuture<Void> in
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        self.send("hello world new ok", to: channel).flatMap {
            channel.writeAndFlush(HTTPServerResponsePart.end(nil))
        }.whenComplete {
            channel.close(promise: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

There's one assumption I'm making here which is that `self.send` is okay with being called from any thread and doesn't use `ChannelHandlerContext` that you might have stored on `self`. To assess if `self.send` is okay here, I'd need to know what exactly it does.

---

As an aside, in your first code snippet, you have a redundant `eventloop.execute`:

```
public func channelRead(context: ChannelHandlerContext, data: NIOAny) {
   // eventLoop.execute not necessary here
   context.channel.getOption(HTTP2StreamChannelOptions.streamID).flatMap { streamID -> EventLoopFuture<Void> in 
        // ...
        var buffer = context.channel.allocator.buffer(capacity: respBody.count)
        buffer.writeString(respBody)        
        context.channel.write(self.wrapOutboundOut(HTTPServerResponsePart.body(.byteBuffer(buffer))), promise: nil)
        return context.channel.writeAndFlush(self.wrapOutboundOut(HTTPServerResponsePart.end(nil)))
    }.whenComplete { _ in
        context.close(promise: nil)
    }
}
```

The `context.eventLoop.execute` is unnecessary because any event on a `ChannelHandler` is *always* invoked in the correct `EventLoop`.

Comment: I am passing the context to the `send` function. I have updated the question with that snippet.

Comment: @jsloop it seems to be a `context: StreamContext`, I assume that's not NIO's `ChannelHandlerContext`, correct? If that's accurate, then from NIO's perspective, there's nothing wrong with your `send` function. Of course, you still need to follow the usual thread-safety requirements. If for example `getHeaders` gets written from one of NIO's threads and then read on a `DispatchQueue`, you'll need a lock or so for that. Have you tried ThreadSanitizer?

Comment: `sendHeader` is same as `sendData` which uses `HTTPServerResponsePart.head` to write the header. The channel is passed around. Currently none of the methods use GCD. The `StreamContext` is a struct with request specific state which currently contains only the `streamID`. I planning to use GCD only within the top level handler `context.channel.getOption..` which will call send. The send will then write the header and then body and close the channel within that GCD block. I think this is safe as the header and body is not written in separate threads, right?

Comment: @jsloop Cool, that seems safe then :). If you want to be 100% sure, you could make `sendData` and `sendHeader` a `static func`, then there's no risk you access something from `self` that you'd need to lock. As an aside: Given that you use `Data`, don't forget to `import NIOFoundationCompat`, that will make it a lot faster to work with `Data` if you haven't already.